# Using the output of "du" for math in a shell script (need to strip suffix)

Tags: shell, bc, du

i have this code

```
strg=`du -s -BM /path/folder` 
dstrg=5120 
num=`expr $dstrg -$strg`
num1=`echo $num\* 100 |bc`
num2=`echo $num1/5120 |bc`
echo $num2
```

i get to the variable strg the folder usage at mb and then 
I want to use it to remove it from the available space that is 5gb 
but i got syntax error

Comment: i forgot to put it here i have it in my shell script

Comment: BTW, in general, `$(( ))` should be used instead of `expr`. Since `expr` is an external command, it's vastly more expensive to run than shell-internal math.

Comment: yes sorry my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an integer result suffices, you don't even need `bc` -- and in no circumstances is `expr` advised for use with modern shells:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- ensure that bash extensions are available

declare -- strg=$'4096M\t/path/folder'  # possible result of strg=$(du -s -BM /path/folder)

strg=${strg%%M*}   # delete everything after the first M in the string, inclusive

dstrg=5120

num=$(( ( (dstrg - strg) * 100) / 5120 ))
echo "$num"
```

...properly emits `20` as output.

---

See:

- [Parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) -- the syntax used in `${strg%%M*}`. Also see [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), describing string manipulation in bash in general.
- [Arithmetic expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/arith) -- describing `$(( ))`, the modern syntax (for all shells compatible with the 1991 POSIX sh standard) replacing `expr`.

Comment: why is `strg=${strg%M}` not enough?

Comment: @karakfa, see the hardcoded sample output on the first line of this answer as-edited -- at least where I'm testing, the output of `du` contains the directory name (and we have no guarantee that directory name won't itself contain a `M`). `${strg%%M*}` could suffice, though.

Comment: that work with 2 or 1 %  on strg=${strg%%M} but can you explain me how that line delete everything after M include this or send me a link cause i just try to find this solution 2 days

Comment: @AndreasXatziosHadjiconstanti, you need two or else it'll misbehave if there's a `M` in the filename. Read the "parameter expansion" link. [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) is also a helpful resource.